# No Console.logs showing up in Chrome or ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am not sure what the problem is, im assuming its something with the way my angular routing is? If anyone could help that would be very appreciated.

This is my controller, the console log here actually prints.

```
  app.controller('ClientCtrl',['$http','$scope',
  '$stateParams',function($http,$scope, $stateParams){
  var clientid = [$stateParams.id];
  var client = this;
  client.infos = []
  $http.get('../client.JSON').success(function(data){
    client.infos = data;
    console.log(client.infos)
  });
}]);
```

This is my routes, im using ui.router, since im using angular. the client route is the one causing problems.

```
planoxApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/templates/index.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
    })
    .state('clients', {
      url: '/clients/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'clientsmain.html',
      controller: 'ClientCtrl'
    })
    .state('photoplans', {
      url: '/photoplans/:id',
      templateUrl: 'photoplanmain.html'
    });

}])
```

This is the html file thats causing me problems

```
<h1>Hi! </h1>
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="info in client.infos" >
    <p>{{info.active}}</p>
</div>
<script> console.log("this sucks") console.log(client.infos)</script>
```

And this is the console right now

[image]

I have tried everything i can think of to get this to work, but nothing works currently. As you can see angular is not throwing errors, but nothing is console logging from this page nor is the ng-repeat working. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `console.log("this sucks"); console.log(client.infos);`?

Comment: They are not showing up. And i have never seen a console log not show like this. Thats why im baffled by the issue

Comment: @ZoeSteinkamp, he meant you are missing semi-colons. But even if you put them in there, it will print 'this sucks', but then you'll get a ReferenceError because that piece of javascript won't know about your `client` variable.

Comment: Actually it prints neither client sucks or the client.info. Neither console log, and i added the semi-colons

Comment: @AndrewMairose partials will never consider the script tag..and they don't load it..look at mine answer..

Comment: Thanks everyone! Im not sure how i missed the fact patials cant load console logs,  im new to angular and im sure this is a newbie mistake. Also not using controllerAs syntax is just silly. But thank you guys for the help, hopefully in the future this can help someone else.

Comment: @ZoeSteinkamp its javascript concept, not an angular concept..

Comment: I suppose i should say i dont work often in the front end, and i have never had the chance to use partials in a javascript language. But thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already printed a result from the angular `controller` in console its there in screen shot.

Seems like you should us `controllerAs` alias there for controller, you could declare alias inside your state itself like by doing `controller: 'ClientCtrl as client'`

**Markup**

```
<h1>Hi! </h1>
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="info in client.infos" >
    <p>{{info.active}}</p>
</div>
```

**State**

```
.state('clients', {
   url: '/clients/{id}',
   templateUrl: 'clientsmain.html',
   controller: 'ClientCtrl as client'
})
```

**Update**

You can not load script from the partials, they will never get readed when they are loaded through the partial html. Though using `console.log(client.infos)` never make sense how can you think of angular context will available for the global script.

If you want it something like this then you could take a look at [**this thread**](https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006), but my personal advice is you shouldn't go for this.

Comment: So you fixed the ng-repeat problem, thank you for that. But the script is still not console logging, do you know why that might not be working?

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit! I had no idea Partials did not load console.logs, learn something new everyday. Thank you so much! p.s. i did not downvote.

Comment: @ZoeSteinkamp Glad to help you..Thanks :)